# Prevent insert the same record that comes from clients at the same time with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have Api that config when calling from Clint, it insert a PhoneNumber & Current Date Time.
In my office I have 4 Clint that calling this api at the same time, that will result in 4 inserting data, therefore, I add conditioner to prevent this situation, the code like this:

```
public bool IsExistIn10Seconds(string number)
{
    var item = DbContext.Histories
               .Where(o => o.Number == Number && 
                           o.EntryDateTime.DateTime >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10))
               .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Code used for Insert Data:

```
public void Save(History model)
{
    var exist = _historyRepository.IsExistIn10Seconds(model.Number);
    if (exist) return;
    _historyRepository.Add(model);
    _historyRepository.Save();
}
```

If any record exist in `item` variable, that means record already add, But this solution is not working and in production stage, it still add 4 records.
[image: result after publish in production stage]
is there any solution to Prevent multiple insert in same time (Entity Framework, MVC Core 2.0)

Comment: Please can you provide the full piece of code? You mention inserting records but there is no code for inserting.

Comment: @Luke question update!

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve as in what is the issue?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu because all clients add the same time calling api, all of them at the same time check for existence record, and because the result all of them is not exist, they will add same record to database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using Locking principle:

```
public class LockObject
{
    public static object LockObjectSatet = new object();
}
```

And Then:

```
public void Save(History model)
{
    lock (LockObject.LockObjectSatet)
    {
        var exist = _historyRepository.IsExistIn10Seconds(model.Number);
        if (exist) return;
        _historyRepository.Add(model);
        _historyRepository.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, this is an option, but it has some limitations. One running process at any time. Some threads will wait. And it doesn't protect from dupes in final, It could be insert from some other place in code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want uniqueness on some field you can add Unique Index on the field. This will prevent from dupes in table. You will have exception on attempt of multiple insert.
Another approach is you could use db transaction with serializable isolation level to read existing rows (check existence) and write new row in one transaction. It will also lead to exception on multiple insert.

Answer (score 0):

If they are child records e.g. Phone number entiry is a parent that has history you could enforce adding via the parent phone number and use a timestamp property on the parent for concurrency control. http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency. If just individual records db unique index is probably best. If you need to do it in app you would probably need to enforce it via reservation pattern or locking.

Answer (score -1):

Check if there is any duplicate entries in the database that have the same details as what you're trying to add. If not, then it's a new version and you should add it, if so then it's a duplicate and you should do whatever you want to handle that situation.

```
if (repository.Get(x => x.Major == newVersion.Major && 
    x.Minor == newVersion.Minor && x.Build == newVersion.Build)
    .Count() > 0)
{
     //notify the user that they are making a duplicate entry
}
else
{
     repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538859/entity-framework-how-to-prevent-duplicate-entries-into-db)